# Installing TauDEM in Linux

Tags: installation, linux, taudem

I would like to install a version of TauDEM above 5.3 (current version is  5.3.8) in Linux Ubuntu 16.04. Installation instructions that I have managed to find online are [here](https://github.com/solomonvimal/TauDEM-QGIS), [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html#installing-taudem-under-linux) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346775/how-to-solve-building-error-where-a-variable-was-not-declared-in-this-scope). And the errors that I get when I try these instructions are reported [here](https://github.com/dtarb/TauDEM/issues/149) and [here](https://github.com/dtarb/TauDEM/issues/125).

TauDEM source code is linked [here](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/downloads.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution however is on the Github website here - [issue 149](https://github.com/dtarb/TauDEM/issues/149). The issue had to do with the develop branch of TauDEM which seems to have some bug.

Answer (score 1):

To install Taudem in GNU/Linux Debian you can download installation script from: taudem_ubuntu.tar.bz2

in this link:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346775/how-to-solve-building-error-where-a-variable-was-not-declared-in-this-scope